# Cocoa HUD Window: remove transparency?

Tags: cocoa, hud, nstoolbar

I have a standard NSPanel set to HUD style.  I want to change the background color, primarily because I want to have a toolbar and don't see any way of making either a standard nstoolbar look good on a HUD nor a way of customizing the background of a toolbar directly.

I am aware of the multitude of ways for creating a completely custom window, and use those in other circumstances.  In this case, I want all of the good things that a window provides, but I just don't want transparency.  Interestingly, I can change the background color, but not the alpha.  Setting alpha values has no effect on the window.

Anyone solved this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Set the panel's content-view's (just click inside the panel to select it, not the titlebar) subclass to `SGPanelView` and make that `SGPanelView` with this implementation of a drawRect method of your class: SGPanelView, a subclass of NSView:

```
- drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyrect {
  [[NSColor blackColor] set];
  [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]];
}
```

Should work. If not working, try changing `bounds` to `frame`.

---

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html for more information.

Comment: No can do - the toolbar is actually not part of the contentView's drawing.  The toolbar draws over the window's background directly, not the content view.

Comment: Use `[[window contentView] superView]` to get the window's view. Note that you've to alter the rect because it includes the title bar.